# Android: Facing issue while migrating NDK from 10 to latest(23)

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build

We have one android project with ndkbuild. We are using NDK version r10e and want to migrate it to latest version(r23b). But we are facing below error.

error: use of undeclared identifier 'catopen
error: use of undeclared identifier 'catgets'
error: use of undeclared identifier 'catclose'

Please respond if anyone has faced this issue and resolved it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's not enough information in this question. For example, what is your `minSdkVersion`? The functions mentioned in those error messages weren't introduced until API level 26.

Comment: Hi @Michael, Thanks for your response.
my minSdkVersion is 21. And the error got resolved when i changed minSdkVersion to 26. But the problem is the users with Android version below 8 won't be able to install my app. That's why I am looking for other ways to fix the issue.

Comment: If you need those functions on older Android versions then you'll probably have to provide your own implementations of them.

Comment: The errors are from Locale file which is generated by NDK itself. We won't be able to edit anything there right?